# Create multiple nodes and relationships with parameters

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create something like attachments to an email.
So I have an email information array like the following:

```
email: {name: 'aUniqueString'}
attachments: [
   {label: 1, filename: 'a.jpg'},
   {label: 2, filename: 'b.jpg'},
   {label: 3, filename: 'c.jpg'},
]
```

If I had to enter only one attachment, this should work:

```
MATCH (n:email {name: "aUniqueString"})
CREATE (a:attachment {filename: 'a.jpg'})
CREATE (n)-[r:ATTACHMENT {label: '1'}]->(a)
```

How would I create all attachment nodes at once and connect them to the email node (with a single query)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass them in as parameters you can do:

params:

```
{ email: {name: 'aUniqueString'}
attachments: [
   {label: 1, filename: 'a.jpg'},
   {label: 2, filename: 'b.jpg'},
   {label: 3, filename: 'c.jpg'},
]}


CREATE (n:Email {name: {email}})
foreach (att in {attachments} |
   CREATE (a:Attachment {filename: att.filename})
   CREATE (n)-[:ATTACHMENT {label: att.label}]->(a)
)
```

FOREACH works on collections, see also here:

- http://neo4j.com/blog/oscon-twitter-graph/
- http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-foreach.html
- http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-cookbook-pretty-graphs.html